# The entity type 'List<Guid>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

The entity type 'List' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I already define Id as the primary key here. but still, it's failing the Dotnet test case.

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

public List<Guid> Books { get; set; }
```

Comment: have you tried with "IEnumerable<Guid>" instead of "List<Guid>"?

Comment: You might want to tag this with 'Entity Framework' or something like that.

Comment: You're defining `Id` as the primary key on that class, EF is complaining that there is no primary defined on the `Guid` class to make a 'foreign key'-style connection to. Do you have a table called "Books" that you're trying to build the model for?

Comment: @Daevin yes I have "Books" model too.

Comment: @Daevin should I need to use "List<Id>" instead of this??

Comment: @ParasDalsaniya then I think you want `public List<Book> Books` instead.

Comment: but Id is type of "Guid"

Comment: That doesn't matter. Entity Framework does the thinking about that for you. On this class, you just want to be able to access a list of `Book` objects, so you need to create a `List<Book>`.

Comment: @Daevin is there any way to use "List<Guid>" ? I will try "List<Book>".

Comment: Why use `List<Guid>` instead of `List<Book>`? An ORM's job is to allow you to work with objects without bothering with their mapping to tables and FKs

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Book class would fix this. Then use `List<Book>` instead of `List<Guid>`.

Comment: Please show us how?

Answer (score 0):

If your `List<Guid> Books` is not part of your database model, you can decorate it with `[NotMapped]`.

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
[NotMapped] //<<---Added this
public List<Guid> Books { get; set; }
```